# Javascript go back with query added to url

Tags: javascript, redirect

on my logout page I redirect users back to the last page they was on, but I'm currently trying to add `&msg=2` onto the URL, but I can't work out how to do it. I've tried doing

```
<script>
  history.back(-1) + "&msg=2";
</script>
```

But surprise surprise, it doesn't work. So any ideas how I would do this? Sorry for such an easy question, I'm kinda new to JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems a little fragile. It will fail (or at least do something unexpected) if, for example, another site links to your logout URL. You also don't have access to the history URLs, you can only tell the browser to go forwards or backwards.

I would approach this by adding a URL parameter to your logout script that contains the URL of where the browser should go afterwards (the *continue* URL). The server serves a 302 to the continue URL with the added parameter, or defaults to your home page.

Pseudo code:

```
handleLogout(httpRequest){
  doLogout();
  queryParams = httpRequest.getQueryParameters();
  if (queryParams.get('continue')):
    continueUrl = queryParams.get('continue');
    redirectUrl = continueUrl.appendQueryParam('msg', '2');
    return Http302Response(redirectUrl);
  else:
    return Http302Response('my_home_page');
```

Comment: I used to do this, but I thought it would be nicer to do what I asked how to do, but I never really thought about the " if, for example, another site links to your logout URL", because it was always only going to ever be a small site. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
window.location.replace(document.referrer+ "&msg=2");
```

Comment: Lol, unfortunately I still get a 404.

Comment: what are the urls of the pages before and after the logout

Comment: Logout is just /logout And the page before is /pages/test/header.php and after the 404 is /?msg=404